# Kotlin/JS — Compile a JS library with types defined in NPM dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, kotlin, npm, kotlin-js

I’m trying to write a library using the new Kotlin/JS IR compiler. Specifically, I want to write the library using Kotlin, but to publish it as a NPM package to be used in a Typescript/Node project.

I have a NPM dependency in the project defined which already has TS types defined and a readily available.

To allow the library to work smoothly together with using it in tandem with this dependency in a project it would make sense to use the already defined TS types when available.

As an example, I want to define a function in my library `foo(message: Message)` where `Message` is actually a type coming from the NPM dependency.

What I hoped to be able to achieve would be an output where the generated types in my compiled output contained something like this:

```js
import * as someDep from 'some-dependency'

export namespace foo.bar.baz {
    function foo(message: someDep.Message): void;
}
```

However, I haven’t been able to get this done. Instead, the Message is simply just there as an undefined type, meaning the `d.ts` file is essentially broken.

For an example of a simple project which tries to do what I’m asking about see: [GitHub - jsfr/sample-kotlin-js](https://github.com/jsfr/sample-kotlin-js)

Here I create a simple abstract class named `Consumer` which should be able to take a `Message` type from the external `google-protobuf` NPM library. However, in the resulting `d.ts` file the Message is present with no definition of itself.

Is what I’m trying to do here possible or is there some other approach I should take instead? This seems like an important thing to be able to do for good interoperability.

Comment: I feel your pain. I have been trying for days now to find just SOME way of creating a web front end based on business logic in kotlin. I have tried kotlin with react, kotlin with compose for web, and - as you - generating a js module for use in fx Angular or React. I haven’t been able to make any of it work for my usecase. Either the support isn’t there or the documentation is simply non-existing.